# Magento multi site - How does cache management work and have to clear cache?

Tags: magento-1.6, cache

I am having problems with the cache on 1 domain. I have a multi domain magento v. 1.6.

I have made some changes to a CSS file and cleared cache, but it have only updated on 1 domain. I have 3. I have seen in var folder that there are 3 folders, cache, cache1 and cache2. Can I just delete the contents of them without it have any negative effect on may site?

I have flushed the cache and storage in cachemanagement. But does it effect all 3 sites?

Comment: Meta is the site for questions about the Magento SE site. The Magento SE site is where your question belongs, so I will move it there :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge, There is not any scope for cache by store. And cache1 and cache2 folders have been renamed from cache folder to regenerate cache immediately. Yes, It will regenerate cache for every store.